# ngResource collection return

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I get a single result from my array `$scope.trailers`. When I try to access the first index by `$scope.trailers[0]` I get undefined. I am using ngResource to do the API call

```
        function getTrailers(pageNo){
            pageNo = typeof pageNo !== 'undefined' ? pageNo : 1;
            $scope.trailers = apiservice.getTrailers().query({page: pageNo});

            vm.trailer = $scope.trailers[0];
        };
```

$scope.trailers structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/105uv.jpg

I figured out its not working because of async. How would I make a promise on that query getTrailers function?

Comment: Can you show the structure of `$scope.trailers`?

Comment: Can you provide an example fiddle if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Accessing 1st result in array will be $scope.trailers[0] , so you have to check if either the array is filled or the array is associated array.

If it is associated array then you have to use string as a key/index instead of number. Ex : $scope.trailers["numberone"]

If you dont know the key then you can use the following code

```
for (var key in $scope.trailers) {
console.log($scope.trailers[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve I had to use the $resource $promise

```
           vm.trailers = getTrailers().$promise.then(function(data){
                vm.trailers = data;
                vm.trailer = vm.trailers[0];
            });

        function getTrailers(pageNo){
            pageNo = typeof pageNo !== 'undefined' ? pageNo : 1;
            return apiservice.getTrailers().query({page: pageNo});
        }
```